# What could possibly go wrong when not locking write operation here?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Assume a class `WorkerThread` that implements a field `running` which indicates whether the thread should continue to work after it was started or not.

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):

    running = False

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            # .. do some important stuff
            pass

def main():
    t = WorkerThread()
    t.start()

    # .. do other important stuff

    t.running = False
    t.join()
```

Is there something that could possibly go wrong when modifying `t.running` from the main thread, without locking the read and write operations to this field? What is it?

Comment: Not an answer, but You could try using a lock instead. Have the thread have a `threading.Lock` instance, have the `main` method acquire it. In the `run` method, use `while not self.lock.acquire(False):`, then release in main when you are done. The `False` argument to acquire makes it non-blocking, and will just return `False` immediately is if can not acquire it (because `main` has not released it)

Comment: Example: https://gist.github.com/dbowring/d480fde90930184a4f44

Answer (score 1):

The main thread and the worker thread could run on cores that do not share cache. Because of the absence of synchronization, the write to `t.running` might *never* be shared from the main thread's cache to the worker thread's cache.

What synchronization *means* is not just "I want exclusive access". It also means, "I want to share my writes to other threads, and see the writes from other threads". No synchronization means that you do not need those things. Not synchronizing doesn't prevent them happening (and on some systems/architectures they will happen with more frequency than others), it just fails to guarantee they will happen.

In practice you might find that provided CPython is taking the GIL at regular intervals, these things sort themselves out even on architectures that, unlike Intel, do not have coherent caches.

Answer (score 1):

for your requirements use a `threading.Event()` object instead a *flag*.

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self.running = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        self.running.set()
        while self.running.is_set():
            # .. do some important stuff
            pass
    def halt(self):
        self.running.clear()

def main():
    t = WorkerThread()
    t.start()

    # .. do other important stuff

    t.halt()
    t.join()
```

and for check if is running `t.is_alive()`.

Answer (score 0):

The field "running" is shared state, you need to guard it with some kind of monitor. In the absence of synchronizing access to this shared state, its visibility semantics are difficult to reason about and you'll get unexpected results.